# Android activity as dialog, but without a title bar

Tags: android, webview, titlebar

I have an activity that has the following set as theme:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

However, there is a title bar in the activity-dialog that appears, that uses up the little available space that I have. How can I remove it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you post a Screenshot of it?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Try doing `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in `onCreate`. It'll need to be done immediately after calling `super.onCreate` and just before `setContentView`.

Comment: Have you tried this with 2.2? I am getting a `Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features` Exception, but maybe I am doing something else wrong.

Comment: You're probably using another window title feature in code, or using a theme that does other things to the title.

Comment: this wll not work in `AppCompactActivity`. You sholud add the @zackygaurav answer so that the user who are using the `AppCompatActivity` will get the proper information.

Comment: @Moinkhan so how would it work for 'AppCompactActivity'?

Answer (score 145):

For those who are using `AppCompatActivity`, above answers may not work.

**Try this**

`supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

immediately before `setContentView(R.layout.MyDialogActivity);`

Comment: Or add `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` to your style i.e. without the **android** prefix

Comment: Just one more thing: Do not use `ConstraintLayout` at the root of your layout or your activity will not appear on screen.

Answer (score 114):

You can define your own theme:

```
<style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

(Tip of the hat to @Rehan) If you're using the compatibility library, you should pick an `AppCompat` parent theme and leave off the `android:` prefix. For example:

```
<style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's probably a better approach, but I ended up using requestWindowFeature. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Just adding: Use it without **android** prefix for `AppCompatActivity` i.e. add `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` to your style.

Comment: I've found good concept on many sources but none of them talking about AppCompat and none-Appcompat, thanks

Answer (score 30):

If you are using `AppCompatActivity` in which you are forced to use `Theme.AppCompat.xxx` for everything, you can remove the dialog title or actionbar in `styles.xml` using this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Notice the use of `name="windowActionBar"`, instead of `name="android:windowActionBar"`.

Comment: I was trying helplessly using AppCompat AND using android namespace in the windowNoTitle declaration. THANKS!

Answer (score 7):

This one worked for me.

I was able to disable the title

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppDialogScreenTheme" parent="Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppDialogScreenTheme">

  </activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me for appcompat.

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using AppCompatActivity requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) is not working.

for this you can create custom theme in values/style.xml as below:

```
   <style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

**please note that item name:"windowNoTitle" not 
item name:"android:windowNoTitle"**

In menifest.xml apply this custom theme as

```
<activity android:name=".activity.YourActivity"
            android:theme="@style/NoTitleDialog"/>
```

or you can use **getSupportActionBar().hide()** to programmatically hide action bar.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, may it helps someone too :

**style.xml**

```
<style name="NoTitleActivityDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <activity
        android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleActivityDialog"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
but not working for me, if you are like me so do this :
first Add the following code in your res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item></style>
```

Pass the theme to your dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.NoTitleDialog);
```

that's it very simple