# Hiding Dialog's titlebar in Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Basically, I created an Activity inside a dialog, everthing is seems working perfectly but the problem is the title bar of a dialog is still there. Is there anyway to hide it?

And also this is the tutorial, here is the [link](http://www.geekmind.net/2010/06/android-open-new-activity-as-dialog.html). It is exactly what I am trying to accomplish except witout title bar.

Note: THIS IS NOT JUST AN ALERTDIALOG OR DIALOG, THIS IS AN ACTIVITY INSIDE A DIALOG which only became looks like a dialog by pasting the code below.

```
<activity android:label="My Dialog (activity)" android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

[image]

Comment: try after removing: android:label="My Dialog (activity)"

Comment: If I remove it, it will be replaced with my original application name

Comment: This link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title

Comment: It is activity inside a dialog and not a dialog inside an activity

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325018/android-activity-as-dialog-but-without-a-title-bar Defining your own theme is a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove the title bar programatically.

Add this line to your Activity onCreate() method.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**Edit:**

Create a custom style that extend Theme.Dialog:

`<resources>`

```
<style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>`
```

`</resources>`

Then reference this theme in your activity android:theme attribute. :)

Comment: @Leon then try to set the dialog title to ""

Comment: @Lean The solution is to create a custom theme. I've edited my answer check above.

Comment: @Leon :what error u r getting..?In onCreate() it should just after calling super.onCreate().

Comment: How would I use the NoTitleDialog?

Comment: @Leon android:theme="@style/NoTitleDialog"

Comment: If you are using the setContentView method of the dialog, the requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); should come before that.

Answer (score 10):

If ur using appcompat support v4, v7 libraries then try using

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

before `setContentView` and also before `super.Oncreate();`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with such, easiest solution:
In Manifest 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
Seems to work.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

**style.xml**

```
<style name="NoTitleActivityDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <activity
        android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleActivityDialog"/>
```