# UI freezes on removing white screen before splash

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, splash-screen, app-startup

I am trying to remove white screen before splash so i followed solutions mentioned in these links

[How To fix white screen on app Start up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up)

[White screen before splashscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067615/white-screen-before-splashscreen)

I tried almost every solution mentioned here

which includes changing activity theme to this

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

or adding this to my theme

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

but implementing any of this freezes the UI for a while on click of the App icon after that everything works fine as desired.

Has anyone succeeded to fix this lag. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Might as well look here [Launch Screen pattern]: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shaishav but i can't follow all the guidelines mentioned here as my splash screen is dynamic i.e things keep on changing in this screen :(

Comment: Anyone downvoting this question.Kindly help me to get the solution.If you find this question improper feel free to edit it.Thanks.

Comment: @Shaishav Thanks your answer has shown me the right way. It definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom theme like,

```
 //splashTheme
 //create in styles
 <style name="splashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

and then apply the theme as follows,

```
 //manifest file
 <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.splashTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this did not helped :(

Comment: what is the issue ? can you post the screenshot ?

Comment: I can't take the screenshot of the lag.The UI hangs for a while just before opening the app.The lag is between the app open and app icon click

Answer (score 0):

following changes work for me on mac:

```
1.Goto android studio preferences.
2.In Build,Execution and Deployment select "Instant run".
3.disable-Enable instant run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy.
4.apply changes,clean project and rebuild again.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but please go through my question again.This is not i am looking for... :)

Comment: use this in custom style <item name="windowDisablePreview">true</item> instead of <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>

Comment: how they the first is different than the later.

Comment: please check my answer this work for me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325018/android-activity-as-dialog-but-without-a-title-bar/38720020#38720020

Answer (score 0):

Finally got my answer [Splash Screen in Right Way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/). I do just following.

In values-->styles.xml I created splash screen background image

```
<style name="Splash" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

For below api 19, in values-19->styles.xml I used

```
<style name="Splash" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

I removed setContentview() from SplashActivity and added style for splash screen in Manifest.xml file android:theme="@style/Splash"